# How can I test a consensus protocol that I created?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

Currently, I am designing my own blockchain consensus protocol and I want to test its performance. Is there any available tool or well-known framework that gives me this ability?

Comment: Check parity substrate , you can there implement your own Blockchain and change what ever you like

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will check it!